# Short story where aliens provide choice of escape from Earth to all species. All leave except for dogs, which remain with behind with humans

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

Short story where aliens provide a choice of escape from Earth to all the species.  All leave except for dogs, which remain with behind with humans.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Please look at our [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) to see more kinds of questions you could remember answers to, and then [edit] more details into your question. For example, approximately when did you read this? Was it a physical book, a magazine, an e-book, online, etc.? If it was in a collection, do you remember anything else about the other stories? If it was in a physical book, do you remember anything about the size or cover? Was it in English? Etc.

Comment: This has some similarities with Dodie Smith's [*The Starlight Barking*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Starlight_Barking), but in that book, only dogs are offered the chance to escape, not all species.

Comment: All species? Humans and dogs left on an Earth without plants, fungi, or bacteria? What do they eat?

Comment: @user14111 if all species are offered a choice, perhaps we can assume that ‘all’ in this instance means ‘all sentient’?

Comment: @Spagirl How much difference does sentience make? Most sentient creatures would be incapable of understanding the choice, much less making their wishes known. But it may be different in the fantasy world of the story. I was trying to get the OP to clarify the scope of "sll species".

Comment: @user14111 tbh I thought you were being a bit sarcastic rather than asking the OP for info. Sorry to have misjudged that.

Comment: Do you remember why the aliens offered it?

Comment: @user14111 "Humans and dogs left on an Earth without plants, fungi, or bacteria? What do they eat?" Both species eat meat, and there would appear to be plenty on offer. It's not an ideal diet for humans, but it seems pretty good for dogs. ;-)

Comment: There is a short story - or maybe a play - within one of the Arthur C Clarke ocean-focused novels like this. It's more of a parable though, where humans will be condemned to extinction unless two other species speak in their favour. The dog steps forward at that start, and then many other species demur, before humanity is finally saved by the mosquito.

Comment: More details would help distinguish variations on this theme.